# Check S3 File Size Using DAG In Airflow

Tags: python, if-statement, airflow

I'm currently trying to write a dag to copy files from one S3 location to another. Before I can copy the files, I need to check the corresponding reject file to see if it is empty. The logic I need to follow is:

```
if rej_file_size = 0kb:
    Copy files from S3_loc_1 to S3_loc_2
else:
    Fail dag
```

I'm pretty new to dag and python, so what would be the best way for me to take a file from a location and see if it is empty (0kb) or not (>0kb)

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can't you just make a job in the DAG that checks the file size and raises an error if it is not zero? And set that job to have no retries and make all downstream tasks depend on upstream tasks.

Comment: I could do that if that would be the best practice. My current issue is I don't really know how to check the size of a file in a dag script. Could I use boto3 for this if there is a function built in?

Comment: Oh I see - you could use a python operator with boto3, but are you asking if there is an airflow operator to directly check the file size in s3?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't really word my question well. If a python operator with boto3 inside my dag is the best option, then I would pursue that. Would it be best to use a python operator to check the file size and then determine if the dag continues based off the size of the file?

Comment: Why not just check the file size in the same job that you move the file? Why separate them?

Comment: I could do that for sure too. That does seem to make more sense. I've seen ways online to get the size of a s3 bucket, but how could I get the size of a single file?

Comment: I assume boto3 can do that but that's a totally separate question

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the clarification on this issue Dan!